# Make it easy to suspend all question subscriptions

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, email, subscription

As someone who uses question subscriptions *a lot* (I seem to have 287 of them), there come times when I want to suspend them, i.e. take a vacation from SX.

Currently this is hard - I'd have to manage every subscription *individually*.

Since you recently [redesigned the Email Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906/168273) - could you please add a button to suspend all mails from subscriptions?

Comment: Yeah, a "pause all" button would be nice,.

Comment: Status fulfilled? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature?cb=1

Comment: @Goose: No - try it out. This feature request is about "Question Subscriptions".

Comment: Ah, this is in response to that question. I understand.

Comment: Hm we have some improvements planned for Question Subscriptions, but haven't considered a "suspend" feature. We'll discuss this. Thanks for posting!